# ¿Para que sirve poner final class?

Tags: java

He encontrado un  código que estaba así.

```
public final class MiClase{

}
```

Es algo que no había visto y no sé si sirva para algo colocar **final** antes de **class**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una clase final es simplemente una clase que no puede ser heredado .

imagina que todo el diagrama de clases de tu software es un arbol, y una clase final seria la hoja, te dejo una imagen para que comprendas mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no quiere decir que todas las referencias a objetos de la clase actuarían como si fueran declarados como final.

Answer (score 6):

Significa que la clase no puede ser extendida. Según la [especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2):

> #### 8.1.1.2. `final` Classes
>
> A class can be declared `final` if its definition is complete and no
>   subclasses are desired or required.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if the name of a final class appears in the `extends` clause ([§8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)) of another class declaration; this implies that a `final` class cannot have any subclasses.**
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a class is declared both `final` and `abstract`, because the implementation of such a class could never be completed ([§8.1.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1)).**
>
> Because a `final` class never has any subclasses, the methods of a `final` class are never overridden ([§8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)).

Traducido:

> #### 8.1.1.2. Clases `final`es
>
> Una clase puede ser declarada `final` si su definición está completa y no se desean o requieren sub clases.
>
> **Es un error de compilación si el nombre de una clase `final` aparece en la cláusula `extends` ([§8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4))  de otra declaración de clase; esto implica que una clase `final` no puede tener subclases.**
>
> **Es un error de compilación si una clase se declara `final` y `abstract` al mismo tiempo, porque la implementación de dicha clase nunca podría ser completada ([§8.1.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1)).**
>
> Dado que una clase `final` nunca puede tener subclases, los métodos de una clase `final` nunca son sobreescritos ([§8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)).

Esto significa:

```
public final class NoMePuedenExtender {
    public void noPuedesTocarme() {
        System.out.println("intocable");
    }
}

//la clase de abajo lanza un error de compilación
//puesto que las clases finales no pueden extenderse
//public class IntentareExtenderte extends NoMePuedenExtender { }

//la clase de abajo lanza error de compilación
//el modificador "final" indica que no se puede extender
//mientras que "abstract" indica que debe extenderse
//para poder tener instancias de esta clase
//esto es completamente ilógico...
//public final abstract class ExtiendemeSiPuedes { }
```

Puedes usar este tipo de clases cuando no quieres que otro desarrollador pueda cambiar la definición de los métodos de tu clase. Un claro ejemplo de esto son las clases `String` y los wrappers de los primitivos `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, etc. Nadie necesitaría agregar o sobreescribir métodos de estas clases (esto es cómo los autores de Java diseñaron estas clases, no es mi opinión). Si quieres hacerlo, puedes crear clases utilitarias como `StringUtils` y similares.

Answer (score 1):

Falta únicamente mencionar que es el uso de declarar una clase como `final`.

Extender clases es muy útil, y entonces algo que pasa constantemente en las iteraciones de desarrollo.

Sin embargo hay casos en que la herencia de clases puede causar ambigüedades en código existente.

Por ejemplo, si tengo código en que tengo una clase inmutable `MiClase` que solamente contiene valores finales, y para el sistema es importante que esta clase nunca tiene campos mutables (por ejemplo para evitar lío con múltiples hilos), puede tener sentido de declarar la clase `final`.

También se pueden declarar métodos como `final`, significando que no pueden ser sobreescrito por una subclase. Eso es muy importante en el caso de métodos que se llaman desde el constructor.

Comment: "si tengo código en que tengo una clase inmutable MiClase que solamente contiene valores finales, y para la lógica es importante que esta clase nunca tiene campos mutables, tiene sentido de declarar la clase final." no lo creo. Puedo diseñar una clase `Entidad<T>` que tenga `final T id` en el constructor y que las clases que la extiendan deban declarar registrar el id y demás campos para indicar la inmutabilidad. Un caso donde veo útil definir clases como `final` es si son clases internas de otra clase.

Comment: Dije que tiene sentido, no que sea obligado. Si uno usa objetos inmutables para evitar lío con múltiples hilos, VOs con `final`pueden ser el santo remedio.

Comment: Que la clase sea inmutable no implica que no pueda ser extendida. Ese es mi punto.

Comment: Ah, obvio, disculpa si no dejé eso en clar, español no es mi idioma nativa. Yo me referí a la posible utilidad de garantizar que **queda** 100% inmutable con simplemente no permitir ser extendida. Lo edité para desambiguar.